# Значение слова "бильедушка"

Tags: словообразование, этимология

Встретил в книге "По закону буквы" Л. В. Успенского такое предложение:

> Письмо людям было нужно прежде всего не для писания друг другу «**бильедушек**» и даже не для лавочных счетов.

Грамота.ру молчит по этому слову, а Интернет ссылается в основном на книгу Успенского.

Есть только [одно упоминание](http://bit.ly/2h9UhpK) в книге "Книга превращений. Книга стремлений" Ф. К. Сологуба:

> Смейтесь, смейтесь, — с неудовольствием сказал Иван Степаныч, — а я зато отделался без всяких этаких финтиклюшек, **бильедушек**, да рандевушек.

В тексте книги идёт разговор военных о девушке, поэтому значение слов, по-моему, такое:

- **финтиклюшка** - *легкомысленная женщина*
- **рандевушка** - *встреча*

Кажется мне, что значение - ***не очень важные письма***, а происхождение от словосочетания ***белая душа***, но могу ошибаться.

---

Поэтому вопрос: какое значение у слова **бильедушка** и, если известно, каково его происхождение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Игорь Северянин. ШАНСОНЕТКА ГОРНИЧНОЙ, 1913, июль.

http://lit.peoples.ru/poetry/igor_severyanin/poem_10710.shtml

Но со мною она хладнокровная, ―
Сквозь пять пальцев глядит на меня:
Я ношу **бильедушки** любовные.
От нее, а потом ― для нее.

Бильедушки ― это, вероятно,  письма, записочки.

http://www.bibliotekar.ru/beb/144.htm

фр. billet, от средневекового billetus записка, письмо.

**Из Нацкорпуса:** Вот эти вещицы… **бильедушки,** так сказать… я нашел за подкладкой своей фуражки… [Ф. Д. Крюков. Неопалимая Купина // «Русское Богатство», 1913]

Comment: Там же есть продолжение, из которого ясно, что бильедушки - это  billet doux. [billet doux - это любовные записки (фр.)]

Comment: doux (фр) - мягкий, нежный, billet doux - словосочетание с разным значением:  мягкий билет, нежное (любовное) письмо.